# Subir para o BitBucket um branch já criado

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Tenho um projeto no Git Local e quero subir para o bitbucket, porem ao seguir as instruções:

Get started with command line

> Step 1: Switch to your repository's directory  cd /path/to/your/repo
>
> Step 2: Connect your existing repository to Bitbucket git remote add
>   origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/nutriex_project/checkoutnovo.git git
>   push -u origin master

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

> $ git push -u origin master Warning: Permanently added the RSA host
>   key for IP address '104.192.143.1' to the list of known hosts.
>   Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

[image: gitBash]

Comment: Segue esse tutorial da locaweb, tive o mesmo problema https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/ptbr/Configurando_Github_e_Bitbucket_na_Hospedagem_Linux 1º Definindo Chaves SSH
2º Configurando no Bitbucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Já verificou se voce tem as pemissoes corretas?

Você precisa de adicionar sua chave ssh no bitbucket, Segue o link de um tutorial deles explicando:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa pegar a chave pública do seu computador, que geralmente está em

```
/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

e adicioná-la nas suas configurações do bitbucket.

Na sua conta do Bitbucket, vá em

```
Bitbucket Settings > SSH Keys > Add Key
```

e, na janela que se abrir, você precisa adicionar o conteúdo do arquivo id_rsa.pub